# Difference b/w ls -la and ls -la > ls-1.txt

Tags: linux, bash, shell

If I do ls -la, I get results like

```
total 16
drwxr-xr-x   4 rockse  staff  136 Apr 28 16:55 .
drwx------+ 23 rockse  staff  782 Apr 28 16:48 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 rockse  staff   32 Apr 28 16:49 1.sh
-rw-r--r--   1 rockse  staff  215 Apr 28 17:01 ls-1.txt
```

But if I do ls -la > ls-1.txt, I get this

```
total 8
drwxr-xr-x   4 rockse  staff  136 Apr 28 16:55 .
drwx------+ 23 rockse  staff  782 Apr 28 16:48 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 rockse  staff   32 Apr 28 16:49 1.sh
-rw-r--r--   1 rockse  staff    0 Apr 28 17:06 ls-1.txt
```

I understand that a file is created and then `ls -la` is written to the same but why doesn't it capture the snapshot of `ls -la` before creating the file because we are just writing stdout to a file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirection is done by the shell, not the program you're running. The processing done by the shell to implement this is similar to this (simplified):

1. Fork a child process
2. Open the output file
3. Connect `stdout` to the output file stream
4. Execute the program

Step 2 creates the file, so it will be visible when the program runs in step 4.

If step 2 were done after step 4, it wouldn't be possible to change the program's `stdout` to point to it.